# Error while creating new User (Blazor, REST Api)

Tags: .net, http, blazor

I'm trying to create new User in .Net 5.
What am I doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxA8o.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UserManagment.Models;


namespace UserManagment.Web.Services
{
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public UserService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsers()
    {
        return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<User[]>("api/users/");
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> CreateUser(User newUser)
    {
        return await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<User>("api/users/", newUser);
    }
}
```

}

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UserManagment.Models;

namespace UserManagment.Web.Services
{
public interface IUserService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsers();
    Task<IEnumerable<User>> CreateUser(User newUser);
}
}
```

POST is working fine in Swagger, but since it's my first time working in Blazor, I'm following this tutorial: https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/create-database-operation-blazor/ but he is working in older version, so I don't know if that's the problem.
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Try change from `Task<IEnumerable<User>> CreateUser(User newUser);` to just `Task<User>  CreateUser(User newUser);` on your interface and in your implementation

Comment: i did, still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `PostAsJsonAsync` which has the following signature:

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(
    this HttpClient client,
    string requestUri,
    T value
)
```

Note the return value is a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.  You are trying to assign this to a `Task<IEnumerable<User>>`, hence the error.

A `HttpResponseMessage` contains status info and data. If the data returned is a user object as Json, you may be able to something like:

```
public async Task<User> CreateUser(User newUser)
{
 var response = await this.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<User>("api/users/", newUser);
 return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<User>();
}
```